# Feed CNN features to KNN algorithm in python

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, knn

I want to build an end-to-end trainable model that do:

- extract features from face image by using CNN
- apply KNN algorithm on the previously extracted features

I build my cnn network using python3.5

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=4)

X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')

X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255

Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)    
model = Sequential()
    X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)

    model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, (nb_conv, nb_conv),
                            padding='valid',
                            input_shape=(1, img_cols, img_rows),
                            data_format='channels_first'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, (nb_conv, nb_conv)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(nb_pool, nb_pool)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adadelta', metrics=['accuracy'])


    hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=nb_epoch,
                     verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))

    hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=nb_epoch,
                     verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)
```

and also i have the knn algorithm from https://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-to-implement-k-nearest-neighbors-in-python-from-scratch/

```
def loadDataset(filename, split, trainingSet=[], testSet=[]):
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        lines = csv.reader(csvfile)
        dataset = list(lines)
        for x in range(len(dataset) - 1):
            for y in range(4):
                dataset[x][y] = float(dataset[x][y])
            if random.random() < split:
                trainingSet.append(dataset[x])
            else:
                testSet.append(dataset[x])

def euclideanDistance(instance1, instance2, length):
    distance = 0
    for x in range(length):
        distance += pow((instance1[x] - instance2[x]), 2)
    return math.sqrt(distance)

def getNeighbors(trainingSet, testInstance, k):
    distances = []
    length = len(testInstance) - 1
    for x in range(len(trainingSet)):
        dist = euclideanDistance(testInstance, trainingSet[x], length)
        distances.append((trainingSet[x], dist))
    distances.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    neighbors = []
    for x in range(k):
        neighbors.append(distances[x][0])
    return neighbors

def getResponse(neighbors):
    classVotes = {}
    for x in range(len(neighbors)):
        response = neighbors[x][-1]
        if response in classVotes:
            classVotes[response] += 1
        else:
            classVotes[response] = 1
    sortedVotes = sorted(classVotes.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    return sortedVotes[0][0]
```

I want to use the extracted features from cnn and feed them into the knn algorithm. How can i get, visualize the extracted features and interact with them by taking each k nearest features and classify them in specific group in knn? I cannot able to link the two codes and get the required result.

Comment: Please intend your code in line with PEP8 because it is hard to be read.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow;  it's great that you provided code for the parts of your problem that work; please also provide details about what you have tried so far to get the CNN and KNN parts working together; seeing what you've tried helps others focus their answers on your exact problem

Comment: thank you @landru27 i'm want to get the extracted cnn features in a text file like the file of iris flower presented in the link that enable me to see the data as a dataset and use them in another code such as knn

Comment: when i saved the data using model.save in json, i get a rabish file. how can i get the readable file of features that extracted from layers? is there another way? can anyone please help me.